# RegEx not recognized although it should be

Tags: regex

I'm trying to split texts like these:

`§1Hello§fman, §0this §8is §2a §blittle §dtest  :)`

by delimiter "§[a-z|A-Z
My first approach was the following:

`^[§]{1}[a-fA-F]|[0-9]$`
But pythex.org won't find any occurrences in my example text by using this regex.

Do you know why?

Comment: Do you mean you want to extract those substrings? `re.findall(r'§\w+', s)`?

Comment: That was almost exactly I wanted to achieve. :) I have now `§[(A-Za-z)|(0-9)]{1}` Thank you! Do you know why my regex did not work?

Comment: your two problems were the miss-use of `^anchors$` and the lack of group around the parts of the alternation (which made it `^§[a-fA-F]` or `[0-9]$`). I would have rewrote your regex as follows : `§[a-fA-F0-9]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `^[§]{1}[a-fA-F]|[0-9]$` pattern matches a string starting with `§` and then having a letter from `a-f` and `A-F` ranges, or a digit at the end of the string. 
Note the `^` matches the start of the string, and `$` matches the end of the string positions.

To extract those words after `§` and a hex char after it you may use

```
re.findall(r'§[A-Fa-z0-9]([^\W\d_]+)', s)
# => ['Hello', 'man', 'this', 'is', 'a', 'little', 'test']
```

To remove them, you may use `re.sub`:

```
re.sub(r'\s*§[A-Fa-z0-9]', ' ', s).strip()
# => Hello man, this is a little test  :)
```

To just get a string of those delimiters you may use

```
"".join(re.findall(r'§[A-Za-z0-9]', s))
# => §1§f§0§8§2§b§d
```

See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/p87VtL).

**Details**

- `§` - a `§` symbol
- `[A-Fa-z0-9]` - 1 digit or ASCII letter from `a-f` and `A-F` ranges (hex char)
- `([^\W\d_]+)` - Group 1 (this value will be extracted by `re.findall`): one or more letters (to include digits, remove `\d`)

Comment: Uh, almost! :) I don't want to extract these strings from a text or something, I'd like to split these strings by e.g. §a - §f or §0 - §9

Comment: Please add the expected results.

Comment: I aimed to get a list of substrings: `§1Hello§fman, §0this §8is §2a §blittle §dtest  :)` should get 
`Hello;
man,;
this;
is;
a;
little;
test  :);`

Comment: Thank you but is the last part important? (`([^\W\d_]+)`)

Comment: I am no longer sure what you mean. Do you want to remove those `r'§[A-Za-z0-9]'`? https://ideone.com/p87VtL?

Comment: I mean `§[A-Za-z0-9]` should work too instead of `§[A-Za-z0-9]([^\W\d_]+)` shouldn't it?

Comment: Check https://ideone.com/p87VtL, `re.sub(r'§[A-Za-z0-9]', ' ', s).strip()`

Comment: Yes, `print("".join(re.findall(r'§[A-Za-z0-9]', s)))`

Comment: Too bad it won't work in Java.. String.join() doesn't support regex. Is it possible to use only a split function and regex for this?

Comment: Why use pythex.org then? There is a regexplanet.com to test Java regex. You may use [`s.replaceAll("(?s)(§[A-Za-z0-9])|.", "$1")`](https://ideone.com/sgXdCu). Or `s.replaceAll("(?s)(§[A-Za-z0-9])|(?:(?!§[A-Za-z0-9]).)+", "$1")`

Comment: Thank you! Didn't know that service. Your solution works as expected! Sorry for inconvenience

Answer (score 0):

Your regex uses [anchors](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) to assert the start and the end of the string `^$`.

You could update your regex to `§[a-fA-F0-9]`

Example using split:

```
import re

s = "§1Hello§fman, §0this §8is §2a §blittle §dtest  :)"
result = [r.strip() for r in re.split('[§]+[a-fA-F0-9]', s) if r.strip()]
print(result)
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/LSQK21593)

Comment: Thank you! Um I thought I have to use ^$ everytime I'd like to declare a regular expression. But now it's easy :)

Comment: "end of the line" > end of the string by default, unless you're using a line-by-line tool such as grep or sed, or the multiline flag.

Comment: Thank you again :) Does a regex exist explained in the comments of the other answer?

Comment: @IceTrailer You are welcome. I think that is answered in the last comment of Wiktor Stribiżew.